# Gfci outside near a pond

Tags: electrical

If I have 6 outlets outside near a pond do they all need to be gfci protected or can the first one be gfci and the rest just water resistant ?

Comment: Are they all on the same circuit?

Comment: If all of the outlets are near the pond (even the first one), then I'd protect them with a GFCI breaker back at the panel so the entire run out to the pond is GFCI protected. Otherwise, the "line side" of the first outlet has no GFCI protection. (it's still protected by your grounding system)

Answer (score 2):

All 120V 15 & 20 amp outdoor outlets are required to be protected 2014 NEC 210.8.3. If they are all on the same circuit wire the GFCI outlet from the breaker on the line side. Then the wire that feeds the rest of the outlets on the load side of the GFCI and they will be protected by the 1 GFCI outlet. I would recommend ["while in use" covers](http://www.homedepot.com/p/1-Gang-Extra-Duty-Non-Metallic-While-In-Use-Weatherproof-Horizontal-Vertical-Receptacle-Cover-with-Wasp-Guard-Clear-CKPM/203984705). This type of cover allows the outlet to be used and protects better than the water resistant outlets. I like the metal ones better but they are quite a bit more expensive.

Comment: If the receptacles are outdoors and not under cover (as defined by the NEC), extra-duty (or "in-use") covers are a requirement.